# SharePoint 2013 REST API error

Tags: 2013, rest

I have this working properly on Office 365, but when I move it to our on-premise installation, I get an error.

[image]

here is the code I'm trying to execute

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link  type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.3/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" /> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="../SiteAssets/jquery.dataTables.rowGrouping.js"></script>


Enter State Abbreviation: <input type=text id="stateID" onkeyup="GetZips();"  size=5 maxlength="2">
```

```
<!-- MAKE SURE THAT YOU SPECIFY THE NAMES OF THE COLUMNS TO DISPLAY IN THE  THEAD ROW -->
<h1 id='title'></h1>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="ZipViewTable">
<thead><th>County</th><th>Zip Code</th><th>City</th><th>Timezone</th><th>Area Codes</th><th>Latitude</th><th>Longitude</th><th>Population</th></thead>
```

```
<style type="text/css">

#ZipViewTable
{display:none;}

.expanded-group{
            background: url("../SiteAssets/minus.jpg") no-repeat scroll left  center transparent;
            padding-left: 15px !important;
            font-weight:bold;padding:5px;margin:5px;
        }

        .collapsed-group{
            background: url("../SiteAssets/plus.jpg") no-repeat scroll left center transparent;
            padding-left: 15px !important;
            font-weight:bold;padding:5px;margin:5px;
        }


</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

function GetZips()
{
    var state = ($("#stateID").val());
    if (state.length ==2)
    {
    //
    // MODIFY THE REST QUERY TO RETRIEVE THE FIELDS YOU NEED FROM THE YOUR SPECIFIC LIST
    // YOU CAN TEST YOUR REST QUERY IN THE BROWSER URL TO KNOW THE CORRECT FIELD NAMES TO USE
    // AND TO MAKE SURE YOUR FILTERS WORK
    //
    var call = $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('zip')/items?$select=Id,Title,zip,primary_city,state,county,area_codes,timezone,latitude,longitude&$filter=state eq '"+state.toUpperCase()+"'&$top=5000",
        type: "GET",
        beforeSend: function(){$("#overlay").show();},
        complete: function(){$("#overlay").hide();},
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=minimalmetadata"
        }

    });
    call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
            $("#ZipViewTable").dataTable({ 
                        "bDestroy": true,
                        "bProcessing": true,
                        "aaData": data.value,
                        //MAKE SURE YOU SPECIFY THE FIELDS YOU WANT TO DISPLAY IN THE LIST VIEW
                        //THE VALUE OF EACH "mData" PROPERTY IS THE FIELD NAME AS IT IS RETURNED
                        //FROM THE REST QUERY.  
                        "aoColumns": [
                            { "mData": "county" },
                            { "mData": "zip" },                    
                            { "mData": "primary_city" },
                            { "mData": "timezone", "searchable": false },                    
                            { "mData": "area_codes" },                    
                            { "mData": "latitude" },                    
                            { "mData": "longitude" }
                        ],
                        "iDisplayLength": 100,
                        "dom": '<"top"iflp<"clear">>rt<"bottom"iflp<"clear">>',
                        "bLengthChange": false,
                        "bProcessing": true,}).rowGrouping({
                            fnGroupLabelFormat: function(label) { return "COUNTY: "+ label + ""; } ,
                            bExpandableGrouping: true});            

        $("#ZipViewTable").show();
        $("#title").html("ZIP CODE INFORMATION FOR " + state.toUpperCase());    

        });

    call.fail(function (jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
        alert("Error retrieving Tasks: " + jqXHR.responseText);
    });

    }
}
```

Comment: What version of SP do you have on prem? If SP1 is not installed, then you need to change the accept header to `application/json;odata=verbose`.  <SP1 does not support JSON Light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your version is SharePoint 2013 but without SP1 installed.  If so, [JSON Light](http://blogs.office.com/2014/08/13/json-light-support-rest-sharepoint-api-released/) is not supported.

If so, you could change metadata format from:

```
application/json;odata=minimalmetadata
```

to:

```
application/json;odata=verbose
```

If your version is SharePoint 2013 SP1, then make sure [multiple metadata formats for JSON is turned on](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn762092%28v=office.15%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: changing the metadata format to verbose solved the issue